# Adding values to object from within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Total beginner to programming and node.js

Trying to create an object and add key/value inside another function.

I'm inside an else if block

```
const binance = require('node-binance-api');
     if {
          // some stuff here
     }
     else
     if (
          var _addField={};
          _addField["a"] ="b";
          _addField["c"] ="d";
          binance.prices((error, ticker) => {
               for (var obj in ticker) {
               if (obj.includes(coin + `USDT`)) {
               _addField["e"] ="f";
               }
          }
     })

for (field in _addField) {
     console.log(field);
}
```

The output I get is:
a
c

but not e

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing a callback to the `prices` function.
And so  the `for(field in _addField)` is executed before callback executes.
wrap it with a promise:

```
new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ binance.prices((error, ticker) => {
  for (var obj in ticker) {
    if (obj.includes(coin + `USDT`)) {
      _addField["e"] ="f";
    }
  }
  resolve();
})
}).then(()=>{for(let field in _addField){/*do something*/}});
```